# Include sql file into a SQL Database project programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, t4, sqlproj

I am using t4 templates to generate code.

One of the parts I am generating is sql code and I would like to add it to a SQL DB project in my solution.

What I tried so far is:

```
var p = new Project($@"..\..\..\{projectName}\{projectName}.sqlproj");
p.AddItem("Compile", $@"..\..\..\{projectName}\{folderName}\{fileName}");
        p.Save();
```

However it fails on the **new Project** part already. Error:

> Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: 'The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

However the .sqlproj is there.
What I am trying to achieve is not only adding the file itself to the project, but make it **included** as well in the build.

Is there another way or am I doing something wrong? I am using .net Framework.

Comment: Did you Google for `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" was not found`?

Comment: @mjwills yeah but from what I understand many of the reported problems happen at compilation time while mine is at runtime..

Answer (score 0):

If you want just add a file, try the overloaded constructor with IgnoreMissingImport flag, it worked for me:

```
Project p = new Project($@"..\..\..\{projectName}\{projectName}.sqlproj", null, null, new ProjectCollection(), ProjectLoadSettings.IgnoreMissingImports);
```

You can find more information about Project Constructors [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.evaluation.project.-ctor?view=msbuild-16#Microsoft_Build_Evaluation_Project__ctor_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary_System_String_System_String__System_String_Microsoft_Build_Evaluation_ProjectCollection_Microsoft_Build_Evaluation_ProjectLoadSettings_)